# Execute Async Tasks one after another

Tags: java, android-asynctask, android-volley

I know that there are already some discussions and I searched on the internet a lot for a solution, I have 3 get calls (volley) I want to execute one after another because the next get does need variables which were set on the get before this but it doesn't seem to work here. When I debug the whole process it worked fine of course but when running the app normally it doesn't get any data which I would have gotten when debugging it.

Now I tried to set static boolean variables to make this whole thing work but theres so far no success..

```
public class AsyncToken extends AsyncTask<String , Void, Void> {

private PacketBuilder pb = new PacketBuilder();
private Context context;
AsyncUser u = new AsyncUser(context);

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    while( task1finished == false )
    {
        try
        {
            Log.d("App", "Waiting for GetTask");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Log.d("App", "GetTask finished");
    // Do what ever you like
    // ...
    pb.Get("token", "", params[0], context);

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String ... params)
{
    task2finished = true;

}

public AsyncToken(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

}
```

EDIT, the code:
[image: Code where i start the first asynctask, in the end i check if the object i should have gotten with get is there, if yes, i start another activity]

[image: first asynctask]

[image: last asynchtask]

Answer (score 2):

When async task is completed `onPostExecute()` is called, so start another async task with computed values there. You can have global variables what should be computed or you can pass them through parameters.

```
//start first async task
new TaskOne().execute();


class TaskOne extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
    String tmp;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... records) {
        tmp = computeNeededValue();

        return tmp;
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        new TaskTwo().execute(tmp);
    }
)

class TaskTwo extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... records) {
        //use computed value from first task here 
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //start another async task
    }
)
```

Comment: I tried this solution and to check if this does work i checked if the variables i got from the get were set, nothing, im getting this error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference. And either i am debugging wrong or it doesnt jump into onPostExecute.

Comment: edited it, first one is the execution of the first task, where i also check after every task has finished if i got the object with the get, if yes i start a new activity, second picture is the first task, third the last task.

Comment: You have mistake in the condition "if(finish = true)" (should be "if(finish == true) or if(finish)") what is always true so it starts doing code in cycle with uninitialized data. But I would delete that cycle and run code from there in onPostExecute() of last async task when you will have all data initialized.

Comment: i changed the code like you said, thank you for the help but when i debug (also when i run it normally) it doesnt start the intent, when debugging and trying to jump over looper.java i cant go much further than this:  https://www.pic-upload.de/view-34123441/Capture.png.html after i reached this point the debugger says "The application is running" and nothing else happens